# How to hide Cursor line in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I am using a dark theme for eclipse, but I have some problems with the cursor line.Can annyone help me to get rid of the cursor line. I want to say thanks, to all that will help me.
Image link: http://snag.gy/MNUG5.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

1. Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors
2. Check or uncheck "Highlight current line" if you check, you can change color by
3. In the scrolling list at the bottom, set "Current line highlight" color whatever you want.